# How is throwing an exception across DLL-boundaries implemented?

Tags: c++

I just implemented a little program in C++. One DLL that has a exported function that throws an exception and one exe that calls this function that catches this exception. Both are totally independent compilation- and liking-units. But surprisingly catching the exception works.

The nearby implementation for the C++ exception-handling I imagine is that when throwing an exception there's not only the object created that will be thrown but there is some type information passed alongside with the object that will help to identify if a catch-clause is compatible, i.e. a kind of RTTI for catch-clauses. But this won't work if this type-information would exist twice in two translation-units.

So how is this implemented???`

Comment: The DLL and the executable are part of the same process, share the same stack etc, so provided you compiled both with the same compiler, there should not be a problem. This has nothing to do with translation units.

Comment: There is no ABI for exceptions. Meaning that the answer to "how exceptions work" is heavily compiler and/or os dependent. The side effect is: don't expect it to work if the dll and exe are compiled with different compilers. `Both are totally independent compilation- and liking-units. But surprisingly catching the exception works.` There's no guarantee, don't depend on it.

Comment: DLLs are precompiled and linked at runtime. the linker is entirely unaware of them. so there shouldn't be any issue such as _"But this won't work if this type-information would exist twice in two translation-units."_ And I would assume that the type information for the execption in the DLL and the calling executable must be identical in order to produce your expected behavior.

Comment: No, this isn't a duplicate question. I'm asking not if this is possible, but I'm asking how this is implmented!
And to emphasize my question: to catch the exception in the executable the type-information about the thrown exception-object must be passed across the call. But this type-information is built independently for the DLL and the executable!

Comment: @Bonita If the DLL and the executable are compiled with the same compiler there is no more issue here than there is with static linking.

Comment: You don't understand what's the problem: There must be something similar like RTTI so that the unwinder can match the catch-clauses against the thrown object. But if I build the executable and the DLL indivdidually, this type of information would be stored twice that the thrown object can't be matched.